# How to cover RTLD_DEEPBIND

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries, dlopen, dlsym

I would like to `dlopen()` a dynamic library `liba_new.so` which was created by `g++ ../include/a.cpp -fPIC -shared -o liba_new.so -std=c++11 -lpthread`. But in the application loading it, i will hook the `pthread_create()` like

```
extern "C" int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
        void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg)
{
    pthread_create_fn f = (pthread_create_fn)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "pthread_create");
    printf("hook my_pthread_create, origin fn=%p\n", f);
    return f(thread, attr, start_routine, arg);
}
```

in the lib will use pthread_create like this:

```
static void* thread_fn(void*)
{
    for (;;) {
        sleep(1);
        auto f = get_loop_func();
        f();
    }
}

int create_thread()
{
    pthread_t pid;
    int res = pthread_create(&pid, NULL, &thread_fn, NULL);
    return res;
}
```

when dlopen like

```
auto handle = dlopen ("liba_new.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_DEEPBIND);
create_thread_fn fn = (create_thread_fn)dlsym(handle, "create_thread");
```

the `pthread_create` in main can't hook the `pthread_create` in `liba_new.so`.
what should i do that i can hook the `pthread_create` in `liba_new.so`.
i can't unuse `RTLD_DEEPBIND`.

Comment: What do you mean by "the pthread_create in main can't hook the pthread_create in liba_new.so"? The function in your library name is `start_routine`, so obviously `pthread_create` will not use that.

Comment: I think using `RTLD_DEEPBIND` and hooking with `RTLD_NEXT` is contradictory. Can't you just pass your own `pthread_create_fn` function pointer to the library's function as an ordinary parameter? That way you don't need to hook it via dynamic linker magic.

Comment: @P.P No, `start_routine` is a function pointer parameter, the OP failed to include complete `pthread_create` prototype.

Comment: @yugr Maybe. But hard to tell. How the dlopen'ed object is used isn't shown and how the hook is supposed to work (or what's not working) isn't shown, either.

Comment: @P.P, 
There is a part that was not shown just now, I have modified it.

Comment: @Erlkoenig 
I cannot modify the source code of the so library。for example，the so will use pthread_create by
 `static void* thread_fn(void*)
{
    for (;;) {
        sleep(1);
        auto f = get_loop_func();
        f();
    }
}

int create_thread()
{
    pthread_t pid;
    int res = pthread_create(&pid, NULL, &thread_fn, NULL);
    return res;
}`

Comment: @simulatorz It's not fully clear to me. Your `create_thread` function in liba_new.so will need to be `extern "C"` for you to be able to locate the symbol. Assuming that does have it, what exactly is failing? dlopen returns NULL? dlsym returns NULL? When calling the dlsym'ed object you get error?

Comment: @P.P,i can run `create_thread` function in liba_new.so,but the thread will not print `hook my_pthread_create, origin`. i need hook the thread which create in the liba_new.so.

Comment: @simulatorz ok, now, I *think* I understand. (Still you'd be better off posting a [mcve]). If you want to use symbols from main, can you compile it wiht `-rdynamic` (to export symbols from it).

Comment: @P.P，you can look the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63132603/how-to-modify-symbol-address-in-so)