# How to modify symbol address in so

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries, dlopen, dlsym

I have a liba.so.
the a.h is:

```
#pragma once
#include <functional>

extern "C" {

void set_loop_func(std::function<void()> fn);

int create_thread();

}
```

the a.cpp is:

```
#include "a.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex g_mtx;
std::function<void()> g_fn;

extern "C" {

void set_loop_func(std::function<void()> fn)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(g_mtx);
    g_fn = fn;
}

std::function<void()> get_loop_func()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(g_mtx);
    return g_fn;
}

static void* thread_fn(void*)
{
    for (;;) {
        sleep(1);
        auto f = get_loop_func();
        f();
    }
}

int create_thread()
{
    pthread_t pid;
    int res = pthread_create(&pid, NULL, &thread_fn, NULL);
    return res;
}
}
```

i define a pthread_create in main:

```
extern "C" int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
        void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg)
{
    pthread_create_fn f = (pthread_create_fn)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "pthread_create");
    printf("hook my_pthread_create, origin fn=%p\n", f);
    return f(thread, attr, start_routine, arg);
}
```

i want to use the liba.so by dlopen like this:

```
auto handle = dlopen ("liba.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_DEEPBIND); 
create_thread_fn fn = (create_thread_fn)dlsym(handle, "create_thread");  
set_loop_func_fn setFn = (set_loop_func_fn)dlsym(handle, "set_loop_func");  
pthread_create_fn f = (pthread_create_fn)dlsym(handle, "pthread_create");
setFn([]{
            printf("run in loop\n");
        });
int res = fn();
```

the output is:

```
run in loop
run in loop
run in loop
run in loop
```

if i don't use RTLD_DEEPBIND.
the output is:

```
hook my_pthread_create, origin fn=0x7f4db1843990
run in loop
run in loop
run in loop
run in loop
```

i have to use RTLD_DEEPBIND. and i have to hook the pthread_create.
what shuold i do? i guess i can modify the pthread_create address in liba.so when the so loaded.but i don't know how to modify

Comment: RTLD_DEEPBIND tells the linker not to do to the thing you want it to do

Comment: @user253751 so，what can i do？i have to use RTLD_DEEPBIND

Comment: You could just patch the pointer in the symbol table, there're couple project already out there, see: [RuntimeSymPatch](https://github.com/0x0XDev/RuntimeSymPatch) or [fishhook](https://github.com/facebook/fishhook)

Comment: @JohnSmith I found the  couple project can't run on linux？it's only run on macOS。do you have another project run on linux？

Comment: I’m mostly working on macOS, so I’m just familiar with the MachO structure. So for linux, you’d have to look for yourself, but I’m sure, there’re projects for that too

Comment: "I have to use RTLD_DEEPBIND" -- you are not telling the whole story -- _why_ do you need to use `RTLD_DEEPBIND`? See also http://xyproblem.inifo